# Finding LIS in an array of user defined objects based on more than one field

Tags: java

Cracking The Coding Interview(5th ed): Chp 11, Ques 7

**Question**: A circus is designing a tower routine consisting of people standing atop one another's shoulders. For practical and aesthetic reasons, each person must be both shorter and lighter than the person below him or her. Given the height and weights of each person in the circus, write a method to compute the largest possible number of people in such a tower.

My doubt:

- In the solution given in the book it is clearly mentioned in the text
  that sorting the elements will make the solution too trivial then why
  elements have been sorted initially in the code?

> If the elements do not need to stay in the same(relative) order, then
>   we would simply sort the array. This makes the problem too trivial, so
>   let's assume that the elements need to stay in the same relative
>   order.

Here is the code from the book where sorting has been done(First three lines of the code):

```
    ArrayList<HtWt> getIncreasingSequence(ArrayList<HtWt> items)    
    {     
       Collections.sort(items);    
        return longestIncreaingSequence(items);    
    }
```

Comment: Please give a more descriptive title than an abbreviation of the source, restrict yourself to one question per question. Make clear which parts are quoted by using a quote block, and declare the source (not as an abbreviation, not in the title).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Done

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Kindly remove the downvote as I have made the changes you mentioned.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how's the Comparable interface implemented in `HtWt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed solution is composed of 2 steps:

1. sort by weight
2. find the longest increasing subsequence on the heights

The quoted sentence is not relative to the first step, but to the second step (finding the longest increasing subsequence) and it is explaining that we can't just sort the heights because we can't change their order since they are already sorted by their weights.

Take a look at this example with 5 people:

```
weights:  4   5   1   7   2 
heights:  6   3   5   4   1
```

Result after step 1 (sorting by weight):

```
weights:  1   2   4   5   7 
heights:  5   1   6   3   4
```

Now, looking at the heights we can see that the longest increasing subsequence is `1 3 4` which tell us that the solution is composed of `3` people. To obtain that result we can't just sort by heights because since they are already sorted by their weight...

> ... the elements need to stay in the same relative order.

So we need to use a longest increasing subsequence algorithm instead.

Comment: I don't think that it meant to sort on any value at all as it will change the order of sequence. Otherwise it would just become a LIS problem after sorting on any one of the properties which would, as mentioned, be too trivial.

Comment: @GaurangSinghal The quoted sentence is inside the section about the sub-problem of LIS, so about step 2. In this section there is an example of LIS on an array; the quoted sentence is about that example. It is then explained that the same method should be used as step 2 in the main problem, where after sorting by weight we can't change the order of the heights. And yes, the problem is about LIS after sorting on one of the proprieties.

Comment: After reading the problem statement and the solution again, it seems that you were right. This makes it a trivial question though.Though I solved it considering that we can't change the order of elements(not even based on one property) to make it more challenging. Thanks.